# List all Firestore collections using Python admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to get all the collections stored in my Firestore database. I went through the documentation and found that *getCollections()* method on **DocumentReference** can be used if you're using Node.js server SDK. What's the Python equivalent of this?

Comment: See this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76017187/13676217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python SDK has a [`Client.collections` method](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/client.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.client.Client.collections) that lists all top-level collections.

Once you have a document, you can get the subcollections of that by calling the [`DocumentReference.collections` method](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference.collections).

Comment: Done.  If such a thing happens in the future, this was my search query: `google cloud Python SDK Client.collections`

Answer (score 1):

I used this python snippet to go into top-level collection "my-collection" and find a document with a certain "id". Within that document i want to retrieve the documents of the last subcollection, since they contain the last version of the data that I am searching for.

```
fs = firestore_v1.Client()

collection = fs.collection("my-collection")
doc = collection.document("id")
sub_collections = doc.collections()
*_, last = sub_collections

sub_docs = last.stream()
for doc in sub_docs:
    print(doc.to_dict())
```

Note: you have to make a "dummy" entry within the top-level documents, otherwise there is no link between the root collection and the underlying subcollections.