# How to know what collections I have in Firestore using Python API

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Python to conect to a firestore database from a client.

The problem is that I don't know how to see what collections he has in the database:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore


cred = credentials.Certificate('credentials/credentials.json')
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

users_ref = db.collection(u'name_of_colection')
docs = users_ref.stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

I have been looking how to get the name of the collections that he has but I didn't find anything that it was useful to me. I have also tried this:

```
cols = db.collections()
list_col = []
for col in cols:
    list_col.append(col)

len(list_col)
```

I have obtained len = 6

Then I have done this for the different col in the list I have generated:

```
docs = list_col[5].stream()

data = []

for doc in docs:
    data.append(doc.to_dict())
print(data)
```

This data print a dictionary with keys and values, but I don't know only get a list with the name of collections,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you have to get the `id` from each collection (which is the `collection name` you are talking about

```
list_col = []
for col in collections:
    list_col.append(col.id) // <-- add this please
print(list_col)
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Couldn't find this in the current API docs.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe how hard it has been to find on the internet the answer to the question `How to list all collections in Firestore in Python?`. Now, consolidating the answers posted by others, here is the minimal code:

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()

# The following call returns a Python Generator
#     https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/532aff8d7b5bfde8b73be6b7e508f9d9fd6b5254/google/cloud/firestore_v1/client.py#L271-L297
cols = db.collections()

for c in cols:
    print(c.id)
```

Amazingly, the seemingly extensive set of official GCP [Firestore code samples](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples) (or [its corresponding Github snippets](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py)) doesn't have such an example.

This really shouldn't have been such a hard-to-find answer.

Comment: I faced this error. `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

app_options = {'projectId': 'test-project'}
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(options=app_options)

db = firestore.client()
collection = db.collections()
list_col = []
for col in collection:
    list_col.append(col.id)
print(list_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any collection you see in fire base depends on your rights.
you can use

```
query = client.collection_group('mygroup')
or 
query = client.collections()
```

It gives top hierarchy and you have to run multiple times to find the lowest document level.

```
query = client.collection_group('mygroup')
@param {string} collectionId Identifies the collections to query over. Every collection or subcollection with this ID as the last segment of its path will be included. Cannot contain a slash. @returns {Query} The created Query.

collections()[source]
List top-level collections of the client’s database.

Returns
iterator of subcollections of the current document.

Return type
Sequence[CollectionReference]
```